# How to query and echo all data in column using Slim Framework

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a simple highscore system in Slim Framework (still beginner at it), and I get stuck at querying for user datas. I need to query two columns in a table (user, level) and sort it by level (desc).

```
     user
   -----------------------
    id |  name |  level |
   -----------------------
    1  |  Tom  |   10   |
```

Code in pure PHP

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name, level FROM user");
$storeArray = Array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $storeArray[] =  $row['name'];  
}
```

Could someone more experienced provide me a sample of code, that can do what I need ?

Comment: Can you share your php code?.

Comment: STOP using mysql_* libraries AT ONCE! Don't you see they are deprecated?

Answer (score 2):

The php slim code for user resource could be:

```
<?php
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->get('/api/users', function () {

$sql_query = "SELECT id,name, level FROM user ORDER by level DESC";
try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'user', 'password');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $rst = $conn->query($sql_query);
    $users= $rst->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    echo '{"users": ' . json_encode($users) . '}';
} 
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
}    

});
$app->run();
```

I change mysql code to PDO because it's better for security against SQL inyections.

If you access to *yourdomain.com/api/users* you will get the users lists.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know how to ask this, when you have most of the needed code?

With your code:

```php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name, level FROM user ORDER by level DESC");
$storeArray = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $storeArray[] =  array(
        'id'    => $row['id'],
        'name'  => $row['name'],
        'level' => $row['level']
    );
}
```